# Highcharts does not display when a line of PHP header('location...') is added

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display a chart containing dates/time and temperature of a room.

The javascript used to generate the chart is in the temperature.php file which user will be able to view, and the javascript will get data from a dataSorter.php file which contains SQL query to retrieve the results from MySQL for the chart to display.

Javascript to generate the chart in temperature.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 50
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature vs. Time',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Degrees Celcius'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("dataSorter.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

At this point, I have generated 4 drop down lists in temperature.php containing From Date, To Date, From Time and To Time. This will allow users to select a range which they wish to see the chart generate. (E.g 2014-01-20 00:00:00 to 2014-01-21 22:00:00). A button onclick will activate the function:

```
        if(isset($_POST['sort'])){
        $from=$_POST['SDate'];
        $to=$_POST['EDate'];
        $sTime=$_POST['STime'];
        $eTime=$_POST['ETime'];
        $start=$from." ".$sTime;
        $end=$to." ".$eTime;

        header('Location: dataSorter.php?start='.$start.'&end='.$end.'');
        }
        ?>
```

1. $from = start date
2. $to = end date
3. $sTime = start time
4. $eTime = end time
5. $start = combine $from and $sTime to get a start date/time
6. $end = combine $to and $eTime to get a end date/time

dataSorter.php has the following codes:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");

if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("scsense", $con);

if(isset($_GET['start'])){
$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scsenseinfo WHERE roomID='501' AND (dateTime BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') ORDER BY recordID");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'DateTime';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = $rr['dateTime'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scsenseinfo WHERE roomID='501' AND (dateTime BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') ORDER BY recordID");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'RoomTemperature';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows1['data'][] = $r['roomTemp'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);

$help = print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
}

else{

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM scsenseinfo WHERE roomID='501' ORDER BY recordID DESC LIMIT 5) AS tbl ORDER BY tbl.recordID ASC");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'DateTime';
while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows['data'][] = $rr['dateTime'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM scsenseinfo WHERE roomID='501' ORDER BY recordID DESC LIMIT 5) AS tbl ORDER BY tbl.recordID ASC");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'RoomTemperature';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
$rows1['data'][] = $r['roomTemp'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$rows);
array_push($result,$rows1);


$help = print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
}
//header('Location: L501TempSorter.php');

?>
```

If I have header('Location: L501TempSorter.php'); un-commented, the chart does not display a thing, even when onload of the page, without clicking the button to sort the dates. If it is commented, the chart is displayed onload, but clicking the button to sort the dates lead to dataSorter.php and stays on the page, which just displays the arrays containing the sorted dates. I really need help with this, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `header` when you have already printed something, like you sdo with `//header('Location: L501TempSorter.php');`.

If you are trying to save the output from `print` to the variable `$help` than you need to use `sprint` instead. Print will always output to the output buffer and always returns 1. This is true for any print function not starting with a `s` or `vs` the s before the print in the function name always indicates that it will return the resulting string instead of outputting it.

To solve your problem with the data not being displayed please post the onlcick code of the button. It should be an ajax call like

```
<script>
$.getJSON('dataSorter.php', {
     sort:  'sortValue',
     STime: /* get start value */,
     ETime: /* get end value */,
     SDate: /* get start value */,
     EDate: /* get end value */
}, function(data) {
     options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
     options.series[0] = json[1];
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
     /* or anything that updates your chart */
});
</script>
```

In the php script run when the onClick function is executed. You should probably url encode your `Location:` in part

```
<?php
header('Location: dataSorter.php?start='.urlencode($start).'&end='.urlencode($end));
```

Though I don't understand why you are using `header('Location: ...');` here anyways? You are already on the Server why tell the client browser to load a different location just [include](http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php) your script that is supposed to run now.

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose of using location, in case when you use this script only for return json? When you load json in javascirpt, you run your entire php script, so instead od returning json you are redirect to other location, as a result json is not loaded in javascript.